# Allow to view the users rep at the time of posting

Tags: feature-request, reputation, users, revisions-list

Sometimes I see old questions or answers posted by users that *now* have high rep or even are diamond mods. Just out of curiosity, it would be nice to see (e.g. by hovering over the user name) the reputation this user had at the moment of posting.

Comment: I'm sure that this has been asked for before and was [status-declined] but as usual I can't find it right now.

Comment: A rep history widget *should* be possible to build with Greasemonkey and a web service querying the API or a data dump. That would have been a nice entry in the API contest (if this is something the API can do)...

Comment: I really don't see the value ...

Comment: @CRoss: as I said, just curiosity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this would certainly be an *interesting* piece of information, before we can think about implementing something we must ask if it will be *useful* and *beneficial*.

**To What End?**

As we know (and have repeatedly discussed) reputation is not equivalent to programmatic skills, historical reputation *even less so*. Let's take a few examples.

- Jon Skeet and Jon Skeet from 6 months ago: Do we honestly believe that Jon Skeet has become that much *smarter* over the course of the six months? Or is it possible that he was *already* that knowledgeable and his reputation hasn't caught up yet.
- Eric Lippert 6 months ago. He had 1 rep at some point despite being already on the C# team. Again, his reputation simply was no where near representing his level of skill.

**Reputation is not gained by learning**

An interesting, but certainly true, fact. Reputation is gained mostly from answers. This generally means that you are exactly as smart *before* writing a stellar answer as you are *after* it. Obviously, users gain knowledge and skills over time (usually over the course of doing their jobs) this, again, won't be reflected in their StackOverflow score unless they go in and answer more questions, which, as I mentioned usually indicates that they have more knowledge *before* they gain the rep.

### Usability 101: Do not include irrelevant information

If we add a feature which presents users with information they don't need, they will *attempt to factor it in anyway*. We explicitly **do not** want this, because the new information (rep at post-time) is *meaningless* or (at worst) *misleading*.

Comment: Nicely put. By and large rep is function of your *participation* in a site. There are exceptions where people attract massive numbers of down-votes or spam flags, but on the whole the higher the rep the more the user has participated.

Comment: @Chris, and while it's certainly true that brighter users will have an easier time gaining reputation, the correlation is **far** too fuzzy.

Answer (score 5):

The reputation graph on each user's network profile should cover your needs on this.

1. Note the date of the post
2. Click through to their profile
3. Click the **network profile** link on their site profile
4. Click through to the *reputation* tab
5. Follow the arterial clot, or embolism strike point, to the same date of the post.

[image: tear drops on the rep graph show where you should start going to bed crying into your pillow at the overtake of your Meta EXP earn quick cash now]

And there you have the reputation of the user at the time of the post.

Comment: Err... What are these light blue things? Raindrops? Tears?

Comment: It's the tears that flow when you realise your Meta rep has surpassed your SO rep

Comment: @random I never even _started_ with SO rep > meta.SO rep...